# Problem with dotnetopenauth client.ProcessUserAuthorization()

Tags: asp.net, facebook, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I downloaded DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10259 and tried to run the samples, specifically the OAuthClient sample and I managed to get it to work with facebook (VS2010). I can see "Welcome, [my name]" after allowing access in facebook.

The problem comes in when I try to use it in another project. I get a "No overload for method 'ProcessUserAuthorization' takes '0' arguments" and "No overload for method 'RequestUserAuthorization' takes '0' arguments".

Its basically the same code, which I find very weird since it works on the included sample but won't compile in the other project.

What did I miss?

> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>   {
>   IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
>             if (authorization == null)
>              {
>                  // Kick off authorization request
>                  client.RequestUserAuthorization();
>   }
>
> private static readonly FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient
>      {
>          ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"],
>          ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"],
>      };

The FacebookClient class came from the DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock project in the samples included in the 3.5.0.10259 download.

Comment: I think the answer will lie in some part of the code you haven't posted, can you supply more? What is the type of the "client" object in your code? Is is exactly the same type in the example? (not a derived or base type).

Comment: I updated the code above to include the definition of "client"

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can guess is that there is missing overload definitions within the libraries.  I experienced the same issue you are describing, but in my case I couldn't get the samples to compile at all.

The trick though, is to simply pass in a NULL for the request parameter, which seems to work:

```
IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(null);
```

Also note that you may run into the same missing overload issue with the "RequestUserAuthorization" method.  Likewise, you can also pass in null values for each of the three parameters if you don't want to send them along:

```
client.RequestUserAuthorization(null, null, null);
```

Good luck!